# GCP: Number of services limit

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I just realized that in a Google Cloud Platform project one can setup maximum of 20 services per project. That means that a project cannot have more than 20 microservices? Is there any way to increase this limit because in a large application that uses microservices architecture, this will be very usual to have more than 20 microservices.

Answer (score 1):

Go through [Resource Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) to understand how Compute Engine enforces quotas on resource usage and how you can request additional quota.

> ### [Resource Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas)
>
> Compute Engine enforces quotas on resource usage for a variety of
>   reasons. For example, quotas protect the community of Google Cloud
>   Platform users by preventing unforeseen spikes in usage. Google Cloud
>   Platform also offers [Free trial quotas](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/docs/free-trial-quotas) that provides limited
>   access for projects that are just exploring Google Cloud Platform on a
>   free trial basis.
>
> Not all projects have the same quotas. As your use of Google Cloud
>   Platform expands over time, your quotas may increase accordingly. If
>   you expect a notable upcoming increase in usage, you can proactively
>   request quota adjustments from the [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=1.74632657.238999325.1498088887) page in the Cloud
>   Platform Console:
>
> - In the **Quotas** page, select the quotas you want to change.
> - Click the **Edit Quotas** button on the top of the page.
> - Fill out your name, email, and phone number and hit **Next**.
> - Fill in your quota request and hit **Next**.
> - Submit your request.

You can request additional quota based on your needs.

> ### [Requesting additional quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota)
>
> Request additional quota from the [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/quotas?_ga=1.44723815.238999325.1498088887) page in the Cloud
>   Platform Console.
>
> You will receive a response from the Compute Engine team within 24 to
>   48 hours of your request.
>
> We strongly recommend planning and requesting additional resources at
>   least a few days in advance to ensure that there is enough time to
>   fulfill your request.

From your question, it is not quite clear which exact resource you have run out of (I'm guessing [`Backend Service`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service)).

### Kubernetes and Google Container Engine (GKE)

For micro-services architectures, you might also want to consider [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) which lets you orchestrate and build micro-services running in Docker containers with very little management/operations effort required from your side in the long run.

Google provides a managed service called [Container Engine (GKE)](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/) which will take care of managing a Kubernetes cluster without you having to worry about provisioning the instances and getting Kubernetes running on them (this includes upgrades, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I will look into this.